# How to add or remove audio attribute of html5 <audio>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I've created a multi track player whith  html5 and javascript.

```
var track_1 = document.getElementById('audio_1');
```

I've made custom control buttons : volume, play, stop, pause, for example :

```
$bt_play_audio_mixette_1.click(function() {
    if (track_1.paused == false) {
        track_1.pause();
    } else {
        track_1.play();
    }
});
```

I have a button "loop" and i want to modify to `<audio>` attribute `loop` dynamically.

I've tried with `.attr();` or `.prop();` but without success.

do you know what is wrong in this code :

```
var loop_1_active = true;
$bt_loop_audio_1.click(function() {
    if (track_1.prop("autoplay", true)) {
        track_1.prop("autoplay", false);
        loop_1_active = false;
    } else {
        track_1.prop('loop', true)
        track_1.attr("autoplay", true);
    }
});
```

EDIT :

If i use a jquery object :

```
var track_1_B = $('#audio_1');
```

i can't use `pause();`

> error :ReferenceError: track_1 is not defined track_1.pause();

If i use pure JS :

```
var track_1 = document.getElementById('audio_1');
```

i can use `pause();` but i can't change the loop attribute

Comment: are you sure `track_1` is an instance of jquery (initialized in this way: `var track_1 = $(#the_audio_element")`)?

Comment: You should add the piece of code where track_1 is initialized

Comment: @freedev I've updated the question with init code.

Comment: @Szymkowski I've updated the question with init code.

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski What do you mean by "so this is a problem" ?

Comment: @SébastienGicquel please read my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (track_1.prop("autoplay", true)) {` actually sets the autoplay property to true rather than checking if it is true and will always return a truthy value. Use instead `if (track_1.prop("autoplay")) {`. I now see that `track_1` is a dom element and not a jQuery object so it needs to be transformed into one to use `prop()`... e.g. `$(track_1).prop("autoplay")`. Also you can access the element properties directly no need to use jQuery

```
var track_1 = document.getElementById('audio_1');
var loop_1_active = true;
$bt_loop_audio_1.click(function() {
    if (track_1.autoplay) {
        track_1.autoplay = false;
        loop_1_active = false;
    } else {
        track_1.loop = true;
        track_1.autoplay = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This code works fine. However, i've noticed sometimes a bug with chrome and the loop attribute. I've seen a lot of topics about this bug on google so it's not your code, it's a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 3):

use jquery too:

```
var $track_1 = $('#audio_1'); // jquery object
var track_1 = document.getElementById('audio_1'); // pure js DOM element
```

And use jquery methods on jquery object only.

```
$track1.click(//...
$track1.attr(//...
$track1.prop(//...
```

Other methods on DOM element

```
trakck1.pause();
```

Comment: I always read the concole and actually i have only one error : ReferenceError: autoplay is not defined
if (track_1.prop(autoplay, true)) {

Comment: @SébastienGicquel i don't know what browser/debugging tools you are using but [if I try to run it](http://jsfiddle.net/f8apN/) my console shows me an error `track_1.attr is not a function`

Comment: Yeah and that message tells you there in so `attr` function so `track_1` is not instance of jquery

Comment: i don't understand why if i use a jquery object, i can't use pause (); error :ReferenceError: track_1 is not defined track_1.pause(); If i use pure JS var track_1 = document.getElementById('audio_1'); i can use pause(); but i can't change the loop attribute